# How can I access the children of a Silverstripe Page in the Page's controller?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm working with Silverstripe and I'm trying to find out how many children a page has. How could I best do this from the Page_Controller class?

What I'm looking to do is to calculate the height that a navigation DIV in my template should be based on the number of children that it has to display. So I'm looking to right a function that returns [# of Children] * [Height per Child].

Can anyone advise me how I could go about getting # of children to a Page object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` has a [`count()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-ArrayList.html#44-51) function that will return you the number of items in the list.

You can call `count()` on your page `Children` list.

```
$this->Children()->count();
```